# Upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS fails

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, apt, upgrade, package-management

Output of the Bash Terminal: http://pastebin.com/wXKtLzin

I used `apt-get upgrade -f` as well, with the same result.

I only want the 14.04 LTS that works fine and I don't lose my data. In the past the package management system meet my needs with approval. It's sophisticated, but now I really don't know it's better.

In 12.04 I used other package sources for bumblebee and gimp as far as I know. I deleted the sources before I used `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

```
> lsb_release -r
Release:    14.04
```

Comment: Deleting or comenting repositories lines is not enoguth, you need to also remove any package that came from them.

Comment: Does my system work, if I delete these packages and how does I do it. See comment below

Answer (score 2):

To upgrade to a new release you need to use `sudo do-release-upgrade` as `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` just update all packages.

Comment: Ok, I used the graphical Update Manager and I'm already at 14.04, but it doesn't work. No Bumblebee no acceptable graphic output.
But I can't install is. I only can boot a Recovery Console or via a Live CD in a Chroot Environment.
So please help me to get my system work again. What should I do to make it work?